# SQL query not throwing Exception

Tags: php, sql, mysql

This is the piece of code which I have implemented. I have used transactions here for **$query** and **$query2**. Intentionally I have written wrong table name in the **$query2**. So that I can check the transaction is working properly or not. I have tried running the query by **mysqli_query** method and executed both the query. As mentioned above **$query2** is not correct it's intentionally written wrong so if **$query2** is not correct then it should execute second if block statement **if(!$sql2)** and should throw error and should go in catch block and further execute **rollback**

```
mysqli_autocommit($con, false);
mysqli_query($con, "START TRANSACTION");
try{
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3600 second'));
    $pass = md5($password . "1234567890)(*&^%$#@!");
    $query = "INSERT INTO `login` (`id`,`mail_id`,`pass`,`status`) values (NULL,'$mail_id','$pass','Not-verified')";
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO `token` (`id`,`mail_id`,`token`,`exp_time`) values (NULL,'$mail_id','$msg','$time')";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (!$sql) {
        throw new Exception("Error executing query: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    if (!$sql2) {
        throw new Exception("Error executing query: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if ($sql2 && $sql) {
        $check=$mail->send();
        if($check)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Verification mail has been sent ');window.location.href='./login.php'</script>";
            mysqli_commit($con); 
        }
        else{
            mysqli_rollback($con); 
            ?>
            <script>
                alert("Facing some technical issue❗");
                window.location.href="./login.php"
            </script>
            <?php

        }
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
       ?>
    <script>
        alert("Wrong")
    </script>
    <?php
    mysqli_rollback($con); 
}
```

But it's not going in the if block it's gives the following error and closing all the further execution and here line number 99 is : **$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'sitedatabase.token' doesn't exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\events\register.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\events\register.php(99): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO `to...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\events\register.php on line 99
```

I want it should reach in the **catch** block if there is any type of error in executing the query and display that alert and execute rollback

Explained above

Comment: For a start, if you're running PHP older than 8.1, you should add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect` (or `new mysqli`) command, so that such exceptions are thrown automatically by mysqli, so you don't have to tediously write `if (!$sql) {
                        throw new Exception...` for every separate mysqli command.

Comment: Secondly this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and basic syntax errors - please urgently read [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and correct the way you're building your queries...I'm not sure where you learned to write them the way you've shown in your question, but whoever taught you that did you a massive disservice.

Comment: Thirdly, md5 is obsolete for passwords (as per the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)) and not safe anymore. Again I'm not sure where you got the idea to use that - are you following some old or poor-quality tutorial? Use PHP's secure, up-to-date password hashing functions instead. See [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) - and many other links online - for details.

Comment: Beware that writing an access control or login system is _not_ a straightforward task and there are _many_ ways to get it (badly) wrong, some of which you have shown us in your code. It's very much not a topic for a beginner or inexperienced programmer, and needs a lot of research and knowledge. There are also many existing, professional implementations of such systems which you can freely use online - some are built into frameworks, others as libraries, modules or integrations. It might be better to focus your time on learning PHP thoroughly - and adding something unique to your app instead.

Comment: Lastly... `alert("Facing some technical issue❗"); window.location.href="./login.php"` ...using JS alerts and then redirecting is a user experience straight out of the 1990s. No-one will enjoy this. Again, you can no doubt see on other websites what a modern way to approach this kind of situation would be.